# Where does the element gets style in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a template that has various javascript files and plugins.
I want to know in witch javascript file the element get styles and in which line it has been declared

Comment: There is no way to detect this, you would have to look through the files themselves

Comment: You can get this through inspect element in firefox

Comment: You can press CTRL + F in your editor and search for that property or class name or id name or selector.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Javascript gets rendered: open your page in Chrome. Press F12 to open the development tools.
Click the 'search' icon at the left side of the bar, and hover your element. The "Styles" bar at the right side shows which CSS file is used to render the element.

Comment: This is correct for CSS but he's looking for dynamic one, added by Java Script.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your template in browser.
2. Right click on your desired element.
3. Choose inspect element.
4. There you can find the file name in which element in written, style sheet file name and line number if it has.

Answer (score 0):

Use developer console in chrome or firefox to debug and look over the javascript files and use breakpoints for checking the javascript files.

press F12 in chrome to get to developer tools and select Sources, navigate to javascript file which you need to debug.